# Backbone.js _ensureElement error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm getting this error, when I want to initialize the view from router class.

Error is:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method '_ensureElement'

BlogFormView:

```
App.BlogFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".data-form",
    initialize: function(){
        this.template = _.template($("#blog_form_template").html());
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template({blog: this.model.toJSON()}));
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "click .submit-blog" : "submitForm"
    },
    submitForm: function(ev){

    }
});
```

Router:

```
var blog = new App.Blog();
var blogFormView = App.BlogFormView({model: blog});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are missing *new* keyword in router code:

```
var blogFormView = new App.BlogFormView({model: blog});
```

Also, it usually isn't best idea to call render inside the *initialize* method. I personally would just call *render* inside the router code.